# IntBinaryOperator to String in Java

Tags: java, casting, tostring

Is it possible to cast an IntBinaryOperator to a String in java?
What I have here is a simplification of the program I want to run

```
import java.util.function.IntBinaryOperator;
public class Showcase {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        IntBinaryOperator op = (a,b) -> a + b;
        System.out.println(op.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of output do you want to accomplish? The IntBinaryOperator is a FuntionalInterface and cannot provide a custom toString method

Comment: You can create a string from an `IntBinaryOperator` the way that you do, but it will not return the source code (i.e. not `(a,b) -> a + b`) - this information is lost during the compilation of the java source code.

Comment: I know that it is a functionalInterface, but i would like to print out which lambda function it represents. toString() ist just an oversimplification of what I would like to accomplish with my code. It would be great if I could print (a,b) -> a + b into the console

Comment: Thanks Thomas, at least now I know that it is impossible

Comment: You are effectively asking if you can print the source code of a method. The answer is no, this is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement `IntBinaryOperator` as a class rather than a lambda, and override `toString()`:

```
IntBinaryOperator op = new IntBinaryOperator() {
  @Override public int applyAsInt(int a, int b) { return a + b; }

  @Override public String toString() { return "(a, b) -> a + b"; }
};
System.out.println(op);
```

but you have to implement both methods "manually", there's no easy way to get that `toString()` automatically from the `applyAsInt` method, nor to enforce that the `toString()` method is an accurate representation of the logic in `applyAsInt`.